# Finding the page width initially, and checking it after the browser is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize

I have this code working, but it seems clunky to me, is there a way to simplify? The gist of it is I'm checking the page width when the page loads and showing or hiding a div based on that (based on if the browser is wider or skinnier than 480 pixels). Then if the user resizes the browser window, I check the width again and show/hide the proper divs. Anyway this could be simplified with jquery or just js?

```
function pageWidth() {
        return window.innerWidth != null? window.innerWidth: document.body != null? document.body.clientWidth:null;
    }
    //Show/hide the correct div when the page loads
    if (pageWidth() >= 480) {
        $(".siteSearchDropdown").css("display", "none");
        $(".siteSearchSelect").css("display", "block");
    }
    if (pageWidth() < 480) {
        $(".siteSearchDropdown").css("display", "block");
        $(".siteSearchSelect").css("display", "none");
    }
    // Show/hide the correct dropdown when the browser window is resized
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if (pageWidth() >= 480) {
            $(".siteSearchDropdown").css("display", "none");
            $(".siteSearchSelect").css("display", "block");
        }
        if (pageWidth() < 480) {
            $(".siteSearchDropdown").css("display", "block");
            $(".siteSearchSelect").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than writing the code twice, write it once inside the `window.resize` event handler and then trigger a `resize` event on the `window` element:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (pageWidth() >= 480) {
        $(".siteSearchDropdown").css("display", "none");
        $(".siteSearchSelect").css("display", "block");
    }
    if (pageWidth() < 480) {
        $(".siteSearchDropdown").css("display", "block");
        $(".siteSearchSelect").css("display", "none");
    }
}).trigger('resize');
```

Also, since this code will run many times when someone resizes their browser you should optimize your code by caching the selectors:

```
var $siteSearchDrioopdown = $(".siteSearchDropdown"),
    $siteSearchSelect     = $(".siteSearchSelect");
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (pageWidth() >= 480) {
        $siteSearchDrioopdown.css("display", "none");
        $siteSearchSelect.css("display", "block");
    }
    if (pageWidth() < 480) {
        $siteSearchDrioopdown.css("display", "block");
        $siteSearchSelect.css("display", "none");
    }
}).trigger('resize');
```

Note: I mentioned how `resize` event handler code is run many times when the browser is resized. To test this for yourself, just add this code to a page and watch your developer console fly:

```
$(window).resize(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

After looking at the code again you can optimize further by using an `if/else` statement rather than running the `pageWidth()` function twice:

```
var $siteSearchDrioopdown = $(".siteSearchDropdown"),
    $siteSearchSelect     = $(".siteSearchSelect");
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (pageWidth() >= 480) {
        $siteSearchDrioopdown.css("display", "none");
        $siteSearchSelect.css("display", "block");
    } else {//notice the change in structure so the `pageWidth()` function is only called once
        $siteSearchDrioopdown.css("display", "block");
        $siteSearchSelect.css("display", "none");
    }
}).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: I wouldn't trigger a resize initially, that's hackish... if you want the code to run when the page is loaded, just call it when the page is loaded, it's more straight forward.

Comment: I like the way it reads. I find it creates a small amount less overhead and puts all the code in one place (which to me is more readable).

Comment: The last option here is the leanest, and I agree with Jasper, more readable for me.

Comment: I disagree that it's more readable but my point is that it's prone to bugs. If someone else hooks to the resize event, you will be triggering it when you shouldn't and that other resize handler will run when it shouldn't. Not a big deal, but I don't like to code causing side effects.

Comment: @JuanMendes If that's the concern then you can namespace the event: `$(window).on('resize.only-do-this', function () {}).trigger('resize.only-do-this');`: http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events

Comment: @Jasper: I still disagree. I like code that is straight forward to read, that the intention is clear. The intention is clearly to run the same logic when the page is resized and when it's first run. The semantics of your code say: pretend like the page was resized while running this code.  But yes it's true, that a namespaced event would fix the probable bugs. I never knew they could be used for that, I thought it was just an easy way to unbind anonymous even handlers

Answer (score 2):

If you can target CSS3 compatible browsers you should take a look at media queries.  Alternatively there are javascript libraries such as [Respond](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) that provide the same functionality to older browsers.

Comment: Actually, yes, i'm using media queries for some other stuff, might be able to just use it with this too, since i'm just showing/hiding based on screen size.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
function pageWidth() {
    return window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
}

function reconfig() {
    if (pageWidth() >= 480) {
        $(".siteSearchDropdown").hide();
        $(".siteSearchSelect").show();
    } else {
        $(".siteSearchDropdown").show();
        $(".siteSearchSelect").hide();
    }
}

$(window).resize(reconfig);

reconfig();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need function `pageWidth()`, just use `$(window).width()`. Also, you don't have to duplicate the code to show/hide the divs, create a function to do it.

```
function showHide() {
  var isBigLayout = $(window).width() > 480;
  $(".siteSearchDropdown").css("display", isBigLayout ? "none" : "block");
  $(".siteSearchSelect").css("display", isBigLayout ?  "block" : "none");
}


$(window).resize(showHide); //Run when resized
showHide(); // Run initially, or $(showHide) to run after DOM is loaded
```